# How to convert DataFrames to nested lists

Tags: r, regex

Providing the following structure of a `data.frame()`

`var1.gender`
`var1.score.raw`
`var1.score.raw.lower`
`var1.score.raw.upper`
`[...]`
`var2.gender`
`var2.score.raw`
`var2.score.raw.lower`
`var2.score.raw.upper`
`[...]`

How do i convert this to a multi-dimensional list, split by `.`?

Sample data:

`df <- data.frame('var1.gender' = c(1,1,3,3), 'var1.score.raw' = c(12.3, 12.4, 14.5, 13.2), 'var1.score.raw.lower' = c(11,11,13,12), 'var1.score.raw.upper' = c(13,13,15,14), 'var2.gender' = c(1,1,3,3), 'var2.score.raw' = c(12.3, 12.4, 14.5, 13.2), 'var2.score.raw.lower' = c(11,11,13,12), 'var2.score.raw.upper' = c(13,13,15,14))`

The resulting list should look something like this:

```
$var1
$var1$gender
[1] 1 1 3 3

$var1$score
$var1$score$raw
[1] 12.3 12.4 14.5 13.2

$var1$score$lower
[1] 11 11 13 12

$var1$score$upper
[1] 13 13 15 14



$var2
$var2$gender
[1] 1 1 3 3

$var2$score
$var2$score$raw
[1] 12.3 12.4 14.5 13.2

$var2$score$lower
[1] 11 11 13 12

$var2$score$upper
[1] 13 13 15 14
```

Comment: Please provide [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's not clear to me what the desired output is. What exactly do you mean by a "multi-dimensional list"?

Comment: Your output throws out df$var1.score?

Comment: Firstly, you df you provide has a .raw.lower, but you don't want another split by raw, only score. Are you sure you want to split specifically by the period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will edit this in a moment with something that looks at periods in column names (much more complicated) but, without automating, you can create nested lists like so:

```
df <- data.frame('var1.gender' = c(1,1,3,3), 'var1.score.raw' = c(12.3, 12.4, 14.5, 13.2), 'var1.score.raw.lower' = c(11,11,13,12), 'var1.score.raw.upper' = c(13,13,15,14), 'var2.gender' = c(1,1,3,3), 'var2.score.raw' = c(12.3, 12.4, 14.5, 13.2), 'var2.score.raw.lower' = c(11,11,13,12), 'var2.score.raw.upper' = c(13,13,15,14))
df

# changed your naming here to remove the not-needed ".raw."
colnames(df) <- c("var1.gender", "var1.score.raw", "var1.score.lower", "var1.score.upper", "var2.gender", "var2.score.raw", "var2.score.lower", "var2.score.upper")

nested <- with(df, expr = {list(var1 = list(gender = var1.gender, 
                                            score = list(raw = var1.score.raw, 
                                                         lower = var1.score.lower, 
                                                         upper = var1.score.upper)),
                                var2 = list(gender = var2.gender, 
                                            score = list(raw = var2.score.raw, 
                                                         lower = var2.score.lower, 
                                                         upper = var2.score.upper)))})
nested
$var1
$var1$gender
[1] 1 1 3 3

$var1$score
$var1$score$raw
[1] 12.3 12.4 14.5 13.2

$var1$score$lower
[1] 11 11 13 12

$var1$score$upper
[1] 13 13 15 14



$var2
$var2$gender
[1] 1 1 3 3

$var2$score
$var2$score$raw
[1] 12.3 12.4 14.5 13.2

$var2$score$lower
[1] 11 11 13 12

$var2$score$upper
[1] 13 13 15 14
```

Tried to make a dynamic version of this but got lost thinking about recursion. Anyways, this may work if you extend the number of varX you have in your dataset. It's not as clean as doing it by hand and still has a $empty list.

```
nester <- function(df, splitby = "."){
  separated <- strsplit(colnames(df), paste0("[", splitby, "]"))
  # in order to rbind this into a matrix, we have to make all vectors the same length
  n <- max(rapply(separated, length))
  separated <- do.call(rbind, rapply(separated, function(x) {length(x) <- n; x }, how = "replace"))
  separated <- ifelse(is.na(separated), "empty", separated)
  listnames <- apply(separated, 2, unique)
  L <- list()
  # Assumes n is 3. 
  for(L1 in listnames[[1]]){
    L[[L1]] <- list() # create List level 1
    for(L2 in listnames[[2]]){
      L[[L1]][[L2]] <- list() # create List level 2
      for(L3 in listnames[[3]]){
        L[[L1]][[L2]][[L3]] <- list() # create list level 3
        # If no data exists for that list combination ...
        if(length(df[,which(separated[,1] == L1 & separated[,2] == L2 & separated[,3] == L3)]) == 0){
          L[[L1]][[L2]][[L3]] <- NULL # then remove that nested list.
        } else {
          # otherwise go ahead and put that column in as a list
          L[[L1]][[L2]][[L3]] <- df[,which(separated[,1] == L1 & separated[,2] == L2 & separated[,3] == L3)]
          # if data is sitting in a list$empty ...
          if( L3 == "empty" ){
            z <- unname(unlist(L[[L1]][[L2]][[L3]]))
            L[[L1]][[L2]][[L3]] <- as.vector(z) # save the empty L3 to the L2
            #L[[L1]][[L2]][[L3]] <- NULL # and delete the L3
          }  
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(L)
}
df.List <- nester(df, splitby = ".")
df.List
```

Answer (score 2):

By the way "df" is structured one straightforward approach to building the wanted list is to evaluate a call like `list[["X"]][["Y"]][["Z"]][...] = df$X.Y.Z...` for each column of "df". This can be done dynamically by manipulating "language" objects.

Defining a function that accepts a list, a character vector of names/indices and a value to assign at that level, we have:

```
assign_list_element = function(x, inds, val)
{
    cl = bquote(x[[.(inds[1])]])
    for(s in inds[-1]) cl = bquote(.(cl)[[.(s)]])

    cl = call("<-", cl, bquote(.(val))) 
    print(cl); flush.console() 

    eval(cl)  

    return(x)
}
```

Some `bquote` calls could be made simpler or replaced with `substitute`, but, using it as above constructs a better formatted call regarding the indices (for printing purposes).

And, then, for each column of "df", re-structure a -at start empty- list:

```
nms = strsplit(names(df), ".", TRUE)
l = list()
for(i in seq_along(nms)) l = assign_list_element(l, nms[[i]], df[[i]])
#x[["var1"]][["gender"]] <- c(1, 1, 3, 3)
#x[["var1"]][["score"]][["raw"]] <- c(12.3, 12.4, 14.5, 13.2)
#x[["var1"]][["score"]][["lower"]] <- c(11, 11, 13, 12)
#x[["var1"]][["score"]][["upper"]] <- c(13, 13, 15, 14)
#x[["var2"]][["gender"]] <- c(1, 1, 3, 3)
#x[["var2"]][["score"]][["raw"]] <- c(12.3, 12.4, 14.5, 13.2)
#x[["var2"]][["score"]][["lower"]] <- c(11, 11, 13, 12)
#x[["var2"]][["score"]][["upper"]] <- c(13, 13, 15, 14)

str(l)
#List of 2
# $ var1:List of 2
#  ..$ gender: num [1:4] 1 1 3 3
#  ..$ score :List of 3
#  .. ..$ raw  : num [1:4] 12.3 12.4 14.5 13.2
#  .. ..$ lower: num [1:4] 11 11 13 12
#  .. ..$ upper: num [1:4] 13 13 15 14
# $ var2:List of 2
#  ..$ gender: num [1:4] 1 1 3 3
#  ..$ score :List of 3
#  .. ..$ raw  : num [1:4] 12.3 12.4 14.5 13.2
#  .. ..$ lower: num [1:4] 11 11 13 12
#  .. ..$ upper: num [1:4] 13 13 15 14
```

Using this approach, the list is re-structured at every iteration, though its elements are not copied.

Comment: This is outstanding, +1
Other than bquote reading, is there any reading you recommend for familiarizing myself with this dark side of R programming?

Comment: @EvanFriedland : On the same context, you could have a look at the [respective manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Computing-on-the-language) and the general "lazy evaluation" concept.